# How to Connect redis docker container from Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, redis

i am trying connect to a redis docker container from Spring Boot. After searching in google, I didn't found. Please help me to sort it out.

When i try to connect, it show this error:

**Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool**

[image]

[image]

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

//RedisCOnfigurationFIle

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(){
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);

        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);

    }

    public RedisTemplate<String,Object> redisTemplate(){
        RedisTemplate<String,Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setExposeConnection(true);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;

    }
}
```

//My repositryfile

```
   @Autowired
    private RedisConfig redisConfig;
```

Comment: Just curious the spring boot running inside docker container?

Comment: No, it's running normal.

Comment: Can you please post docker config of Redis container?

Comment: @ThangavelLoganathan i could establish the connection. But i can't save value

Comment: but i can see connection failure in your question and error stack trace. Maybe you need to put proper details.

Comment: Later i will add all the details